# Equivalent Java Mat.put() in C# (OpenCV)

Tags: c#, .net, opencv

I have been facing this line of code in a book(JAVA) many times.
It seems like it sets matrix with hardcoded values.

```
Mat src = new Mat(4, 1, CvType.CV_32FC2); 
src.put(0, 0,
    0, 0, 
    img.width() - 1, 0, 
    0, img.height() - 1, 
    img.width() - 1, img.height() - 1 
);
```

And couldn't find what is equivalent to `.put` method in C#.
I have latest 4 version.

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please read the tutorial to learn how to ask. Please explain your code. What is "Mat" and "put" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[put](https://iopencv.com/docs/cpp-python/3.4.2/javadoc/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#put-int-int-int:A-) method inserts data at starting position specified by `row` and `column`.

```
public int put(int row, int col, int[] data)
```

Equivalent in OpenCVSharp is

```
Mat src = new Mat(4, 1, MatType.CV_32FC2, 
    new [] 
    {
        0, 0, 
        img.Width - 1, 0, 
        0, img.Height - 1, 
        img.Width - 1, img.Height - 1 
    });
```

[Documentation](https://shimat.github.io/opencvsharp_docs/html/5f8ff9df-ace7-65d8-adf7-53efa004061b.htm)